# Is it possible to make a RODC to RWDC?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is it possible to make a RODC a RWDC in future or promote it to DC?
We are going with an installation of RODC at a remote site, but in future if circumstances changes and if we had to change it to RWDC is it possible to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to demote it to a member server and then dcpromo it to a RWDC.  The option of RODC or RWDC is only availble to you during dcpromo.